# Unable to use "setValues" in Google Sheets after splitting string into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, split

I'm not sure, why setting values in one go does not work, after I split a text into an array. The error message is a bit strange:

> "Cannot convert array in number[][]"

It works fine though, if I loop through the array and use setValue (without the "s") instead, so I can't figure out what is wrong.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

```
function Replace() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var text ="Might-be-a-system-bug-of-course.";
  var list = text.split("-");

  var listLen = list.length;

  Logger.log(list.length);
  Logger.log(list);

  // This does not work:
  sh.getRange(1, 1, listLen, 1).setValues(list); 

  // This works:
  //for (var i = 0; i < listLen; i++) {
  //  sh.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue(list[i]);
  //}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setValues(Object)) requires a two dimensional array:

```
function Replace() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var text ="It's-almost-never-a-system-bug";
  var list = text.split("-");

  var listLen = list.length;

  Logger.log(list.length);
  Logger.log(list);

  // This work:
  sh.getRange(1, 1, listLen, 1).setValues(list.map(e => [e])); 
  sh.getRange(10, 1, 1,listLen).setValues([list]);

  // This works:
  //for (var i = 0; i < listLen; i++) {
  //  sh.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue(list[i]);
  //}

}
```

Comment: Note: [enable v8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime)

Comment: Great! This solved the issue. I was unaware that setValues requires 2D. Thanks so much, as well for your sense of humor.